# jQuery .on() instead of .delegate() without event

Tags: jquery, jquery-on, jquery-delegate

Is it possible to use jquery `.on()` method instead of `.delegate()` when there is no event to be listened to?

According to the `.on()` documentation:

> .on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler(eventObject) )

The `events` argument is not optional.

The use of `.on()`/`.delegate()` is for elements that are added dynamically.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `on` or `delegate` without an event?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method` Jquery Docs for .delegate()

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but doesn't delegate require an event as well?

Comment: I'm pretty sure delegate requires an event

Comment: Totally true, there is no point on using delegate or on if there is not a event attached. ~Genius~ sorry all.

Comment: well, the question is - what were you trying to do with it? Perhaps it's just a problem of understanding how to solve this initial problem?

Comment: @Christoph the feature is needed to customize an eventsink without modifying jquery source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.on()`s purpose it to attach event-handlers to a certain element, it makes absolutely no sense to use it without an event. That's why the event parameter is required.

From the doc:

> Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Answer (score 8):

You can use custom events:(it IS still an event, but YOUR event )

markup:

```
<div id='mePlease'>
 <div id='noWay'>Hi</div>
</div>

$('#mePlease').on('wacky','#noWay',function(){
   alert('wackyEnough');
});
$('#noWay').trigger('wacky');
```

but really, this could be done with a simple function call.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of these functions is to delegate functionality to events; so no, you can't omit the events parameter from either of these function calls.

I suspect what you want is to "do stuff" to some elements that are loaded *after* page-load (asynchronously), no? Maybe you also need to do this stuff to elements that already exist *on* page-load?

In that case I suggest you wrap your declarations in a function, and call that function both on page-load and once the asynchronous call is complete.